# How to remove Powered by Api.ai sign from chat box?

Tags: bots, chatbot, dialogflow-es

[image]Does anyone know how to remove "Powered by Api.ai" sign from chat box? I found one suggestion that says I need paid account to remove this sign, but api.ai is absolutely free. There is no paid account. Confusing.

Comment: Can you clarify? What platform are you using and seeing this message?

Comment: I'm making a website with chatbot. For chatbot I'm using Api.ai sdk. Powered by Api.ai appears on the chat box. See image above.

Answer (score 8):

This logo can't be removed if you're using [API.AI's web demo integration](https://api.ai/docs/integrations/web-demo) as this is intended for demonstration purposes only.

For production use you can create your own web client using [API.AI's /query API](https://api.ai/docs/reference/agent/query).

Comment: Happy I can help. If you found it useful, please mark the answer as correct and upvote it!

Comment: Matthewayne, unfortunately I can’t vote because of the points. I need 15 points to be able vote. Now I have only 11. If you could up vote for my question, the system will give me 4 points, so it will be 15 and I can vote after that.